# Passing Activity context to Class file

Tags: java, android

I made two classes(DataBase, and addItem to database class) and one activiy. I dont know how to pass Activity class into method. AndroidStudio throws error. 
I tried to use getApplicationContext(), but didnt work. Here is code:

DataBase file

```
   public DataBase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, TABLE_VERSION); }
```

DodajNadgranieClass (fragment) file

```
btZapisz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                String radiobutton = "", bruttoValue ="", data, tytul;
                                SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

                                data = edPodajDate.getText().toString();
                                tytul = edPodajTytul.getText().toString();

                                if (edPodajDate.getText().toString().isEmpty() || edPodajTytul.getText().toString().isEmpty() || radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
                                    Toast.makeText(DodajNadgranieActivity.this, "Musisz podać wszystkie dane", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    if (rbOperetka.isChecked()) {
                                        radiobutton = "1";
                                        bruttoValue = pref.getString("operetka", "");
                                    } else if (rbMusical.isChecked()) {
                                        radiobutton = "2";
                                        bruttoValue = pref.getString("musical", "");
                                    } else if (rbKoncert.isChecked()) {
                                        radiobutton = "3";
                                        bruttoValue = pref.getString("koncert", "");
                                    } else if (rbBajka.isChecked()) {
                                        radiobutton = "4";
                                        bruttoValue = pref.getString("bajka", "");
                                    } else if (rbOpera.isChecked()) {
                                        radiobutton = "5";
                        bruttoValue = pref.getString("opera", "");
                    } else if (rbInne.isChecked()) {
                        radiobutton = "6";
                        bruttoValue = pref.getString("inne", "");
                    }

                    ObliczPodatki obliczPodatki = new ObliczPodatki();
                    obliczPodatki.obliczPodatki(bruttoValue, data, tytul, radiobutton);

                    Toast.makeText(DodajNadgranieActivity.this, "DODANO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    radioGroup.clearCheck();
                    edPodajTytul.setText(null);
                    edPodajDate.setText(null);
```

and Activity file

```
public class ObliczPodatki extends Application {

    public void obliczPodatki (String brutto, String data, String tytul, String radiobutton) {

        kwota_brutto = Double.parseDouble(brutto);
        kwota_netto = kwota_brutto * KWOTA_NETTO;
        kwota_ubezpieczenie_emerytalne = kwota_brutto * UBEZPIECZENIE_EMERYTALNE;
        kwota_ubezpieczenie_rentowe = kwota_brutto * UBEZPIECZENIE_RENTOWE;
        kwota_ubezpieczenie_zdrowotne = kwota_brutto * UBEZPIECZENIE_ZDROWOTNE;
        kwota_ubezpieczenie_chorobowe = kwota_brutto * UBEZPIECZENIE_CHOROBOWE;
        kwota_zaliczka_pit = kwota_brutto * ZALICZKA_PIT;

        sBrutto = "" + kwota_brutto;
        sNetto = "" + kwota_netto;
        sEmerytalne = "" + kwota_ubezpieczenie_emerytalne;
        sRentowe = "" + kwota_ubezpieczenie_rentowe;
        sZdrowotne = "" + kwota_ubezpieczenie_zdrowotne;
        sChorobowe = "" + kwota_ubezpieczenie_chorobowe;
        sPit = "" + kwota_zaliczka_pit;



       DataBase myDb = new DataBase(this);

        myDb.addNewNadgranie(data, tytul, radiobutton, sBrutto, sNetto, sEmerytalne, sRentowe, sZdrowotne, sChorobowe, sPit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using Application and not Activity class . please change it to this :

```
public class ObliczPodatki extends AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: I also tried this. Colud you chceck my gist to see whole code? https://gist.github.com/mrFormax/5341cc671da5fe8ab13ce598c8a45771

Comment: why do you need to application ?

Comment: you should extend your class with AppCompatActivity and implement its method onCreate ....... and use then getApplicationContext or ObliczPodatki .this

Comment: it doesnt work. Only one solution that i found is to move to code from ObliczPodatki class to Activity... But Im not satisfied

Answer (score 0):

You could change the function of `obliczPodatki` to :

`public void obliczPodatki (Activity activity, String brutto, String data, String tytul, String radiobutton) {`

Call it using :

`obliczPodatki.obliczPodatki((DodajNadgranieActivity)v.getContext(),bruttoValue, data, tytul, radiobutton);`

Comment: is `btZapisz.setOnClickListener` inside `DodajNadgranieClass` ? and is `DodajNadgranieClass` a Fragment?

Comment: btZapisz is in `DodajNadgranieActivity`, Dodaj `NadgranieClass` is normal java class

Comment: Oh, in that case, you should be able to do, `obliczPodatki.obliczPodatki((DodajNadgranieActivity)v.getContext(),bruttoValue, data, tytul, radiobutton);`

Comment: It still make this log msg: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
     `

Comment: Can you tell me what line of code causes that error?